# The 'puma' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railsinstaller-windows

I have got this error when running bundle install

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'puma' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

I'm using RailsInstaller which already has DevKit.

I didn't have this problem before but I seem to get it after I changes the ruby version from 2.2.4 to 2.2.5. I'm using a windows computer. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by following these instruction:

- download devkit from here.
- Install the file in DevKit folder
- open cmd and navigate to the folder
- Copy the path of the ruby folder you installed in C drive and paste it in the DevKit\config.yml. Change ‘/’ in the path to ‘\’.

It should look like this:

```
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- C:\Ruby22
```

- Run `ruby dk.rb install`
- Back to your rails folder, run `bundle install` and you should not have any errors